# How would I go about solving for $x$?

Tags: exponentiation, tetration

How would I approach this problem? (Solving for $x$)
$$x^{x}=e^{\Omega}$$
I tried using logarithms and rearranging, but it didn't seem to help:
$$x=e^{\frac{\Omega}{x}}$$
$$\ln(x)=\frac{\Omega}{x}$$
$$x\cdot\ln(x)=\Omega$$
Where do I go from here? Is this a bad approach?

Comment: Do you know about the Lambert $W$ function ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: This does not look like it has a closed form. You could try using the Lambert-W function to get an answer, or use something like Newtons method to get an approximation

Answer (score 1):

The Lambert W function comes in handy, just set the equation up so that $x=W(x)e^{W(x)}$ can be used.
$$x^x=e^{\Omega}$$
$$\Rightarrow x=e^{\frac{\Omega}{x}}$$
$$\Rightarrow \Omega=\frac{\Omega}{x}\cdot e^{\frac{\Omega}{x}}$$
Now you can apply the Lambert W function:
$$W(\Omega)=\frac{\Omega}{x}$$
$$\Rightarrow x=\frac{\Omega}{W(\Omega)}$$
This can still be simplified by rearranging $x=W(x)e^{W(x)}\Rightarrow e^{W(x)}=\frac{x}{W(x)}$.
$$\boxed{x=e^{W(\Omega)}\approx1.47058}$$

Comment: How do you get a numerical value out of the final expression? Are you assuming $\Omega$ represents a particular constant, like $W(1)$?

Comment: No, but you are.

Comment: Then how do you justify $e^{W(\Omega)}\approx1.47058$?